# Is there a way to auto-indent HTML/PHP files?

Tags: php, html, text-editor, autoformatting

My first place to look at this was a fix with Notepad++.
This quite quickly brought me to "TextFX HTML Tidy".

Read the description and it seemed to be the problem for all my problems.

However, the install is quite hard, apparently TextFX used to be standard practice for Notepad++, for some reason that is no longer the case. I eventually fixed this by downloading an older install for Notepad++ and copied the plugin folder to my own Notepad++ file.

This gave me acces to the correct plugin, but this plugin is written purely for HTML, C++, or XML. 
Since I use php in my files, this gives some complications. Normal  tags are ignored as they should be, but when I use php inside an html string, in a link for instance, the php tags get converted to html.

For instance:

```
The start of my sentence <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>" class="something">Here my anchor tekst</a>.
```

After tidy HTML becomes

```
The start of my sentence <a href="%3C?php%20bloginfo('url');?%3E" class="something">Here my anchor tekst</a>.
```

Rendering this solution unusable. 
There must be a lot of people looking for this functionality, and since this one is no longer standard practice for Notepad++, I figured there must be a better method to auto format your HTML code. But for some reason I can't find it.

So my question is: Is there a way to autoformat my code, clearing empty lines and indenting tags in the correct opening and closing order?

Preferably with Notepad++ but any other program will do.

Kind regards

Comment: Netbeans has an code formatter which works really easily with most, if not all, programming languages, including php

Comment: I would also recommend using a PHP IDE like NetBeans or PHPStorm

Comment: Big fan of PHPStorm, however a license is needed, Netbeans is free!

Comment: Netbeans looks so overwhelming compared to something as basic as Notepad++. But it appears to have the functionality I'm looking for. I'll try it out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the same things. Switching to Netbeans did the trick for me, options with Notepad++ are still appreciated.

In Netbeans, using Shift+alt+F did the trick for me.